# How to itemize equation

Tags: beamer, equations, align, itemize

I am using beamer for making slides. In one of my slides, equations appear in bullets. I would like the equations to be aligned. Since these appear in different bullets, I can't use the align option.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\color{blue}{Observations}}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item 1. This bullet has 3 sub-bullets
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Only Text
            \item Text and Equation1 
               \begin{equation}
               f^{r}(\cdot): \{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q^r}
               \end{equation}
            \item Text and Equation2 
               \begin{equation}
                f^{c}(\cdot): \mathbb{Q^r}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q^c}
               \end{equation}
        \end{itemize} 
     \end{itemize}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that you can change the frametitle colour with `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue,bg=white}`?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. One step towards making less cluttered code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a general fix because it allows only one align point (I chose to align around the `:` character, was that the desired point?), and the horizontal centering will be impacted, but if you`\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` the two portions around the align point, then you might get something satisfactory. (I also added `\medskip` to restore some of the lost vertical spacing)

If needed, leftward shift of such equations can be achieved by adding a fixed space after the `\mathrlap{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\color{blue}{Observations}}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item 1. This bullet has 3 sub-bullets
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Only Text
            \item Text and Equation1 \medskip
               \begin{equation}
               \mathllap{f^{r}(\cdot):{}}\mathrlap{ \{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q^r}}
               \end{equation}
            \item Text and Equation2 \medskip
               \begin{equation}
                \mathllap{f^{c}(\cdot):{}}\mathrlap{ \mathbb{Q^r}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q^c}}
               \end{equation}
        \end{itemize} 
     \end{itemize}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]