# Put equation on same line as \item in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, itemize

Consider this standard MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Equation 1 here: 

        \begin{equation}
        Pr( Y= n)  = \frac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!} 
        \end{equation}

    \item Equation 2 here:

        \begin{equation} 
        Pr( Y= n)  = \dfrac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!}
        \end{equation}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

I can do it manually adding `\vspace{-1.05cm}` before both equations. 
Instead, I would like this to be done automatically.

Notice I want to preserve the equation number, so using inline `$ equation $` at the `\item` level is not enough (plus it would need manual centering, depending on equation length.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Related posts that haven't helped me are [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301575/how-to-itemize-equation) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439869/problems-with-spacing-beamer-itemize-and-equation).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129425/equation-equation-number-and-itemize-bullet-all-on-the-same-line). Here are however some minor changes to the most upvoted answer, to my taste:

1. Require the equation to be written inside a math environment. This looks nicer in the editor, as it does not show characters out of place.

   For this change to take place, replace `\sbox2{$\displaystyle#3\m@th$}%` with `\sbox2{#3}%`. Then, use the environment as this:

   ```
   \itemequation{Nice equation}{$2+2=4$}
   ```

   rather than

   ```
   \itemequation{Nice equation:}{2+2=4}
   ```
2. Add option for no equation number (useful with the `$$ ... $$` math environment).

   For this, I created another command, removing the `\sbox4{\@eqnnum}%` line. (I tried creating a star command using `@\ifstar` but failed.